# Banned in desktop, "read-only" on mobile?

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, chat-ban

I have been banned from chat for a week. In that time period, I have found an interesting behaviour of mobile chat.

It shows as I am suspended by a moderator and cannot talk in chat for a week on the desktop, but it shows as 'This room is read-only' in mobile, which it is not.

I can reproduce this bug again.

Image:

[image: It shows as read-only in the bottom]

Comment: And don't you think chat from mobile weird?

Comment: Can you please post screenshots?

Comment: @ShadowWizard posted, It shows as read-only which it is clearly not. (sandbox is an open chatroom)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that looks like a duplicate.

Comment: I know, that's why I voted to close.